# Is ElasticSearch safe to allow every node to join cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch open port 9300 for node-to-node communication, and every machine in the same `network` with same `cluster.name` can auto join this cluster?

I doubt is it safe to allow every node to join?

If not, do I need to set `network.host` to a fixed ip address? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the networking stack of your nodes and how you interact with your cluster. If they are all running on a local network, inaccessible from the outside, then in general, allow other nodes to join freely is OK since it means someone from inside your network is trying to join.

However, if your nodes have a public IP address, it's a good idea to change the default ports used, disable Zen multicast discovery, and give each node a list of the other nodes that are allowed to communicate with it.

Straight from the elasticsearch.yml file :

```
# 1. Disable multicast discovery (enabled by default):
#
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
#
# 2. Configure an initial list of master nodes in the cluster
#    to perform discovery when new nodes (master or data) are started:
#
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["enter_ip_here","enter_other_ip:port","etc..."]
```

Note that these settings needs to be the same on all nodes (except for the list of hosts obviously) and a restart of the node is required for these to be taken into account.

Also, you can indeed set the `network.host` to a fixed IP. This IP should be the one appearing in the list of `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`.

Comment: Does `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` means only ip in the list can join the cluster?

Comment: Not exactly; it means that the node with this setting can only join hosts in that list.

Comment: What about other nodes without setting `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`, but with the same `cluster.name` can also join the cluster?

Comment: If you set `discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled` to false, I don't think it'll work.

Comment: So if I want set `multicast.enabled:false`, and set my ips in the `hosts`,  nodes with other ips cannot join the cluster? but the comment says `Configure list of master nodes`, slave may not in the list

Comment: By default, all nodes are potentially master nodes unless you specifically disallow a node from becoming master (using `node.master: true`). Nodes with other ips can join this node if this node's IP is in their list of hosts.